# PullToRefresh list with pinned section header

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

Does anyone has practice of using `Pull to refresh` list with `Pinned section header`?
I use [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) lib with my list and I want to add ability of showing pinned section header at the top of list. I used [PinnedHeaderListView](https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView) lib in another project for pinned section. But I can't combine these two libraries into one.

Is Android-PullToRefresh can show pinned section header? Perhaps any other `Pull to refresh` lib can do it?

Comment: In my opinion you should use [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) because Android-PullToRefresh has not been supported for 5 months.

Comment: Great comment, I have to pay attention to the lib. But I'm not sure it supports pinned header.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. So far my only conclusion is that I have to implement one of the behaviour on top of one of the libraries.. because merging or using both will not work.

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN, you are mistaken, I've implemented this feature. you can check it in xMAP® Kit Finder app on Google Play (at search section). but I have no time to write full answer how I did it... I can send you some my classes. Do you interested in it still?

Comment: Yes I would very much appreciate that, I'm still stuck on this. You can send to the email on my profile. Thanks really!!!

Comment: how you did it??? I also have to implement it, please give me some hints. Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to integrate the [Actionbar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) library with the [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) library, but you need to use a custom Delegate in order to get Actionbar-PullToRefresh to work correctly:

```
public class StickyListViewDelegate extends AbsListViewDelegate {
    @Override public boolean isReadyForPull(View view, final float x, final float y) {
    StickyListHeadersListView sticky = (StickyListHeadersListView) view;
    return super.isReadyForPull(sticky.getWrappedList(), x, y);
}
```

Integrated like so:

```
StickyListViewDelegate delegate = new StickyListViewDelegate();
ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity()).theseChildrenArePullable(mListView)
    .useViewDelegate(StickyListHeadersListView.class, delegate)
    .listener(this).setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
```

The reason that the two libraries don't work together is because the StickyListHeadersListView class does not actually extend ListView (which is what the Actionbar-PullToRefresh library looks for when assigning a delegate by default).

Comment: I tried your solution, but still its not working for me. Any other help can you provide?

Answer (score 4):

I did some research and I found 2 alternatives:

1. [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders). This library is contributed by Jake Wharton ([reference](https://plus.google.com/108284392618554783657/posts/Syv3KpwPMtP)) so it is promising and could be compatible with other libraries. You should try to use it.
2. [PinnedSectionListView](https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview) - easy to use ListView with pinned sections for Android.

You can try combining these two libraries with ActionBar-PullToRefresh. I suppose you can implement the solution ;)

Comment: It's not possible with StickyListHeaders.

The StickyListHeaders implements a "ListView" from a FrameLayout which is not supported.

Comment: just use the inside listview.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) of support-library and the [PinnedHeaderListview](https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView).

In your XML file, use like following:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pinned_lisview_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <za.co.immedia.pinnedheaderlistview.PinnedHeaderListView
            android:id="@+id/event_items_lisview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </za.co.immedia.pinnedheaderlistview.PinnedHeaderListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And then in java code, just write codes for your PinnedHeaderListView as usual. Finally just put a Refresh Listener for your SwipeRefreshLayout like below:

```
pinned_lisview_container
                    .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                        // do your refresh tasks here
                        }
                    });
```

You are done.

Answer (score 0):

SwipeRefreshLayout + any other suitable library that you would use can do the job.
I would prefer PinnedSectionListView  beacuse it uses Listview and it has it its pros in terms of UI/UX.