# pinned headerlistview and pulltorefresh ANDROID

Tags: android, listview

i'm learning using this:-

https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

and modified to add pull to refresh.

Any example headerview with pulltorefresh custom listview?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a combination of SwipeRefreshLayout and ListView. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31874079/2114334